# Saving twitter4j Status object to MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, serialization, twitter, twitter4j

I'm trying to save twitter4j Status object to Mongodb. I have the following code:

```
public void saveTweets(Status status) throws Exception {

    BasicDBObject tweet = new BasicDBObject();
    tweet.put("tweet_id", status.getId());
    tweet.put("user", status.getUser());
    tweet.put("text", status.getText());
    tweet.put("location", status.getGeoLocation());
    tweet.put("place", status.getPlace());
    tweet.put("created_at", status.getCreatedAt());
    tweet.put("contributors", status.getContributors());
    tweet.put("hashtag_entities", status.getHashtagEntities());
    tweet.put("media_entities", status.getMediaEntities());
    tweet.put("user_mention_entities", status.getUserMentionEntities());
    tweet.put("url_entities", status.getURLEntities());
    tweet.put("source", status.getSource());
    tweet.put("retweeted_status", status.getRetweetedStatus());
    tweet.put("retweeted_count", status.getRetweetCount());
    tweet.put("count", 0);

    tweetsDAO.saveToDB(tweetsCollectionName, tweet);
}
```

But this is throwing the below exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class twitter4j.internal.json.UserJSONImpl
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder._putObjectField(BasicBSONEncoder.java:270)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:174)
    at org.bson.BasicBSONEncoder.putObject(BasicBSONEncoder.java:120)
    at com.mongodb.DefaultDBEncoder.writeObject(DefaultDBEncoder.java:27)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:289)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:239)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:204)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:76)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:60)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:105)
```

Seems like i need to go more into the status object and have seperate BasicDBObject for each entities returned. But it is fairly a large task to be done as almost all the status.get*** calls return another twitter4j entity which has set of feilds.

Are there any better ways to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can u post the stacktrace above?

Comment: Is it the complete stack trace? It does not contain the exact location of occurence of the error.Its difficult to tell from above trace what is causing the exception,

Comment: the next line is the code which calls the save. I have already mentioned it above - saveTweets method. There is nothing much after that. I just want to know how to save a object which has references to other custom objects inside. For example, User object will have location object, family object etc inside it, how to save such a combination in MongoDB? Thats the problem here too, twitter4j Status object has other entities internally, so it is not serializing properly to save.

Answer (score 0):

twitter4j's Status object has User object, which is accessible bu getUser(). So when you try to put user by calling **status.getUser()**, you put a class instead of a string, integer or etc.

you can call any method for your user like **status.getUser().getId()** , or make reference to user collection depending on your collection design.

Comment: I have already mentioned the reason... it is straight forward... :) I just wanted to know a better way to save these objects directly without getting each and every field out....

Answer (score 0):

You can get the status as a JSON string, and then parse it to a DBObject like this:

```
import twitter4j.json.DataObjectFactory;
import com.mongodb.util.JSON;

public void saveTweets(Status status) throws Exception {

    String tweet = DataObjectFactory.getRawJSON(status);
    DBObject doc = (DBObject)JSON.parse(tweet);

    tweetsDAO.saveToDB(tweetsCollectionName, doc);
}
```

Comment: This will not correctly parse the date fields. They wil be toString()'ed and nee special treatment.